# git merge/rebase/cherrypick skipping commits on master

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have the following situation:

```
   _____________G ..myBranch
  /
 /
S---B---C1---C2---C3---C..---C230 .. master

S=working version
B=bad version of task
G=good version of task
C=commit after B
```

and I would like to commit and merge the master into myBranch without using B and then merge myBranch into master with the new commits. Is something like that possible with merge/rebase/cherrypicks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do:

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase -i master
```

This will present you with a screen where you can choose which commits to include. Remove the line that has the commit `B`, save, and close your editor.

See also: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: The commit `B` is on the `master` branch, but not on `myBranch`.  Unless the OP drew his tree wrong, it looks like he wants to remove a commit from `master`.  Your interactive rebase steps will only allow for modifying commits in `myBranch`.

Comment: @Bill yeah, either remove it or merge the master into the branch without the specific commit ;)

Comment: @Bill Ah, you're right. I had it backwards. Let me revise.

Answer (score 2):

The *git rebase* answer should work, but if you're wondering how cherry-pick works, you can use use it instead, like this:

```
git checkout myBranch
git cherry-pick C1..master
```

This will create new commits in myBranch based on diffs of commits *C1* to *C230* in *master* (which is the same as what using rebase -i would do).

If you haven't already published *master* and you can just rewrite history, you can use *git reset* to update master:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard myBranch
```

If you *have* published *master*, that is not advisable. Instead, you can merge *master* into *myBranch* using the *ours* strategy, and then merge *master* into *myBranch*:

```
git checkout myBranch
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge myBranch
```

Comment: Sorry about the weird git-read-tree merge strategy in a previous edit.